# copy cells from one sheet into multiple sheets Excel - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, copy-paste

I have data in one sheet in a workbook. I want to distribute it across multiple sheets in a another book. How to do it, here is the diagram.

[image]

Currently I am using the following code but it does not work the way it is suppose too. This is just a starting point for me.

```
Dim row1, row2
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell1 As String

' this is just an example where I am trying to loop through 3 cells but it does not work
' the cells in my example are in G14,G15 and G16


Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

strFirstFile = "c:\Book1.xls"
strSecondFile = "c:\Book2.xls"
Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
For i = 14 To 16
    With wbk1.Sheets("Data")
        Cells(i, 7).Copy
    End With

    With wbk2.Sheets("MyData")
        Cells(i, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    End With
Next i
```

The actual mapping in my example is like this

```
Book1.xls            Book2.xls
sheet1->B3     ->    Company->A3
sheet1->C3     ->    Address->C3
sheet1->E3     ->    Popularity->D3
```

If I can achieve this, my actual project is almost the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution has been sustantially rewritten in light of the revised question.

This solution assumes the macro *SplitSheet* is in its own workbook.  Its needs two file names which are hard coded as *Source.xls* and *Dest.xls* in this version.  This versions assumes all three workbooks are or will be in the same folder.  The source workbook must exist before the macro is run.  The destination workbook must not exist.

The question has four columns but the real problem has sixty.  The solution is designed to resize to the dimensions of *Sheet1* (also hard coded).  Which columns are to be moved, where to and how named are controlled by three arrays which can be enlarged from their current three entries.  The code uses the actual size of these arrays.

I hope that every difficult statement is fully explained.  Best of luck.

```
Sub SplitSheet()

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Integer
  Dim ColMapName() As Variant
  Dim ColMapDest() As Variant
  Dim ColMapSource() As Variant
  Dim ColSourceCrnt As Integer
  Dim ColSourceMax As Integer
  Dim ColWidth() As Single
  Dim DataCol() As Variant
  Dim DataWSheet() As Variant
  Dim FileNameSource As String
  Dim FileNameDest As String
  Dim InxColMap As Integer
  Dim InxWSheet As Integer
  Dim Path As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowSourceCrnt As Integer
  Dim RowSourceMax As Integer
  Dim WBookDest As Workbook
  Dim WBookSource As Workbook

  ' These arrays define the mappings.  Column B is to be copied to column A,
  ' column C to C and column E to D.
  ColMapSource = Array("B", "C", "E")
  ColMapDest = Array("A", "C", "D")
  ' The names to be given to the worksheets in the destination worksheet
  ColMapName = Array("Company", "Address", "Popularity")
  ' Additional entries may be added to these array providing they all have
  ' the same number of entries.

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It can get complicated if more than one workbook is open
    ' at the start.  I suggest aborting in this situation unless
    ' there is an important reason for allowing it.
    ' If this is a one-off transformation, use of Debug.Assert False,
    ' which will stop execution until you press F5, is adequate if
    ' unprofessional.  If it is to be used repeatedly, you need a
    ' proper error message for the user.
    Debug.Assert False      ' execution error
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' This assumes all three workbooks will be in the same folder.
  ' Change as necessary.
  Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  ' You must decide how to assign values to these variables
  FileNameSource = "Source.xls"
  FileNameDest = "Dest.xls"

  If Dir$(Path & "\" & FileNameSource) = "" Then
    ' Source workbook does not exist
    Debug.Assert False      ' execution error
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If Dir$(Path & "\" & FileNameDest) <> "" Then
    ' Dest workbook exists
    Debug.Assert False      ' execution error
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set WBookSource = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileNameSource)

  With WBookSource
    ' Replace "Sheet1" with the name of the source worksheet
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
      ' This determines the highest numbered row and the highest
      ' number column in the source worksheet
      Set Rng = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
      RowSourceMax = Rng.Row
      ColSourceMax = Rng.Column
      ' This copies the values of the entire source worksheet to array SourceWSheet
      DataWSheet = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowSourceMax, ColSourceMax)).Value
      ' This saves the widths of the source columns
      ReDim ColWidth(1 To ColSourceMax)
      For ColSourceCrnt = 1 To ColSourceMax
        ColWidth(ColSourceCrnt) = .Columns(ColSourceCrnt).ColumnWidth
      Next
    End With
    ' We have no further need of the source workbook.  Close without saving
    .Close False
  End With
  Set WBookSource = Nothing

  ' DataWSheet has dimensions (1 to RowSourceMax, 1 to ColSourceMax)
  ' Normal practice is to have rows as the second dimension.  This is not true
  ' of array loaded from or to a worksheet.

  Set WBookDest = Workbooks.Add

  With WBookDest
    ' The factory setting for Excel is to have three sheets
    ' in a new workbook but that setting may be changed.
    ' This Do Loop ensures there are enough sheets and that
    ' any that are added are in sheet name sequence.
    ' It does not delete any excess Sheets.
    Do While UBound(ColMapName) > .Sheets.Count
      .Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    Loop
    ' Name the sheets with the values in ColMapName() and set the
    ' width of the destination column to that of the source column.
    ' The use of lbound (=lower bound) and ubound (=upper bound)
    ' means this for-loop is controlled by the size of ColmapName.
    ' Note one index is used for all three ColMap arrays because they match
    For InxColMap = LBound(ColMapName) To UBound(ColMapName)
      ' ColMapName has been loaded with Array.  Its lower bound is almost
      ' certainly zero but the documentation is not 100% clear that it will
      ' always be zero.  The lower bound for sheets is one.
      ' "InxColMap + 1 - LBound(ColMapName)" performs the necessary adjustment
      ' regardless of the ColMapName's lower bound
      With .Sheets(InxColMap + 1 - LBound(ColMapName))
        .Name = ColMapName(InxColMap)
        ' Convert the column letters in ColMapSource and ColMapDest
        ' to numbers.  Bit of a cheat but it works.
        ColSourceCrnt = Range(ColMapSource(InxColMap) & "1").Column
        ColDestCrnt = Range(ColMapDest(InxColMap) & "1").Column
        .Columns(ColDestCrnt).ColumnWidth = ColWidth(ColSourceCrnt)
      End With
    Next
    ' The destination worksheets are now prepared.
    ' Size the array that will be used to copy data to the destination sheets
    ReDim DataCol(1 To RowSourceMax, 1 To 1)
    For InxColMap = LBound(ColMapSource) To UBound(ColMapSource)
      ColSourceCrnt = Range(ColMapSource(InxColMap) & "1").Column
      For RowSourceCrnt = 1 To RowSourceMax
        DataCol(RowSourceCrnt, 1) = DataWSheet(RowSourceCrnt, ColSourceCrnt)
      Next
      With Sheets(ColMapName(InxColMap))
        ' Copy data to appropriate column in appropriate destination sheet
        .Range(ColMapDest(InxColMap) & "1:" & _
                  ColMapDest(InxColMap) & RowSourceMax).Value = DataCol
      End With
    Next
   .SaveAs (Path & "\" & FileNameDest)
   .Close False
  End With
  Set WBookDest = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I know it is going to be late at your end. I tried this at home with my Excel 2002. I get error repeatedly at `Set WBookSource = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileNameSource)`. In fact I do not get any error, the program just quits at this line. I moved the file to different folder, still the same. I hard coded the file name, still the same. May be will give it a try in office 2007 at work and that might work. I checked security setting but I already set them to low. So dont know why it quits.

Comment: Which version did you use, if I may ask.

Comment: I developed and tested the macro with Excel 2003.  I have just transferred it to another computer with Excel 2007.  The macro worked although when I tried to open Dest.xls it claimed I had the wrong extension.  I assume this is because Dest.xls was created using Excel 2007 and I should have used the 2007 extension (xlsm I think).

Comment: I do not have Excel 2002 but I do have a book about it. The only open I can find uses the .Open Filename:="xxxxxx" syntax but I find it difficult to believe that is important. I have had the symptom you describe about two years ago. It was a much more complex set of macros with deeply nested calls which was mostly working but portions of the task were not being performed. I discovered that the macro would reach a certain statement and then jump up one level with no warning and no error report. I do not remember what type of statement now.

Comment: Having written that, I recall that it was the same type of process. I was consolidating information from 40 or 50 project/department level workbooks into a single company level workbook. I wonder if it was an open statement on that occasion. I sugest you attempt to isolate the problem. Write a macro which does nothing but open and close a workbook. Is it just this workbook? Is it any workbook? Does the Excel version under which the workbook was saved make a difference? I will look through my notes for any mention of the cause of my problem of two years ago but I am not hopeful.

Comment: Great it worked in office 2007. I am going to figure out the logic now. Ideally I would want to copy headers separate from the data. I am not sure if this would be possible with this approach. For example I want to allow user to copy data starting at row 10 to row 20. Thanks

Comment: Very pleased it worked. To allow the user to select a range you will need to use InputBox or a form. I would not interfere with the code at the top. Look 16 lines from the bottom for `ReDim DataCol ...`. The first dimension is the number of rows. I believe the lower bound has to be 1 so the upper bound will have to be RowLast-RowFirst+1. The `For RowSourceCrnt ...`, `DataCol( ...` and `.Range ...` statements will need matching modification. Best of luck.